# Derivation for Specific heat of gas at Constant Volume

Tags: thermodynamics

The mathematical interpretation for first law of thermodyanamics is

$$dU = \delta{Q} - \delta{W}$$

for quasi-static process,

$$W = PdV$$

so,

$$dU = \delta{Q} - PdV$$

Constant volume $dv = 0$

so,
$$dU = \delta{Q}$$

we also know that $U = U(T,v)$

using chain rule we get,

$$dU = \frac{\partial{U}}{\partial{T}}\cdot dT + \frac{\partial{U}}{\partial{V}}\cdot dV$$

again for constant volume, $dv = 0$

$$dU = \frac{\partial{U}}{\partial{T}}\cdot dT$$

so from above equations,

$$\frac{\partial{U}}{\partial{T}}\cdot dT = \delta{Q}$$

$$\implies \frac{\partial{U}}{\partial{T}} = \frac{\partial{Q}}{\partial{T}}$$

Now here comes my question, how did the conversion from $\delta{Q} $ and $dT$ to $\frac{\partial{Q}}{\partial{T}}$ take place?

Answer (score 0):

As $dU=\delta Q$
$$\implies \frac{dU}{dT}=\frac{\delta Q}{\delta T}$$
As $U(V,T)$
So, $$\frac{dU}{dT}=\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}|_V\frac{dT}{dT}+\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}|_T\frac{dV}{dT}$$
For constant volume, $\frac{dV}{dT}=0$
So, $$\frac{dU}{dT}=\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}|_V\frac{dT}{dT}=\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}|_V$$
So, $$\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}|_V=\frac{\delta Q}{\delta T}$$
There should not be $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial T}$ in the RHS of final expression.

Comment: can $\delta$ be used with T is $T$ path dependent?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about concepts and formalism, in particular, usage of $\delta$ for the so-called *inexact differentials*, may be confusing.

Let me restate the problem without using $\delta$, but using the same notation used for example by Planck, who knew quite well Thermodynamics.

The first principle of Thermodynamics says that it is possible to define a function of state $U$, such that
$$
\Delta U_{AB} = w + q
$$
where $w$ and $q$ are the work and heat exchanged in the process driving the passage from the equilibrium state $A$ to another equilibrium state $B$. I am using the *physical* sign convention where $w$ is positive if it increases the energy of the system. Just a change of sign allows to recover the convention used in the question. $U$ is a function of the state. Therefore, for every two states $A$ and $B$ close enough, it is possible to approximate $\Delta U$ by its differential within an error which is second order in the differences between the independent state variables (this is a math theorem valid for every differentiable function with continuous first derivatives).

Thus, for close states $A$ and $B$, and using $T$ and $V$ and state variables, for a constant volume transformation we have
$$
\Delta U = \left. \frac{\partial U}{\partial T} \right|_V \Delta T + 
\mathcal{O}(\Delta T^2).
$$

Now, for a simple system, macroscopic work on the system is zero if volume is constant. Therefore we also have
$$
\Delta U = q.
$$
This is the key point. Therefore, *for an isochoric process*, heat becomes a function of state exactly like, for an adiabatic process work becomes a function of state.

The (differential) specific heat is proportional to the (extensive) heat capacity defined as the limit for $\Delta T \rightarrow 0$ of the ratio between $q$ and $\Delta T$. Then, in the present case we can write
$$
C_V= \lim_{\Delta T \rightarrow 0} \frac{q(\Delta T)}{\Delta T} = 
\lim_{\Delta T \rightarrow 0} \frac{\Delta U}{\Delta T}=
\left. \frac{\partial U}{\partial T} \right|_V 
$$

Comment: "This is the key point. Therefore, for an isochoric process, heat becomes a function of state exactly like, for an adiabatic process work becomes a function of state." I have a problem with these conclusions. Although in each case the energy transfer by work and heat exactly equals the change in state (internal energy), I don't think from that we can conclude that in each case  work and heat are state functions, if that is what you are saying. They are still means of energy transfer.

Comment: @BobD Yes, in that case, they are functions of the state. It is precisely the logical route followed by Caratheodory, Born,  and other guys of the same level to define the internal energy. Of course, it is only in a specific case (adiabatic for work and isochoric for heat) that they depend only on the initial and final state (function of state). But that case, at least for the adiabatic transformation, is of the utmost importance. You may find a thorough discussion of this point in good thermodynamics textbooks like Zemansky-Dittman or Callen.

Comment: You certainly have the heavy weights on your side. Nonetheless, I remain uncomfortable with it. Certainly for the adiabatic process energy transfer by work is solely responsible for the change in internal energy and for the isochoric process energy transfer by heat is solely responsible for the change in internal energy, but I can't see how that makes work and heat properties of the system. I have Zemansky, so I will check out his reasoning. Thanks.

Comment: @BobD I wouldn't like to give the impression that I am using the authority principle.. I cited the fathers of this approach to stress that I am not proposing my own theory. However, to answer the present question, once one has that *for isochoric processes* $q_{iscoh}=\Delta U = U_B - U_A$, what else is required to say that $q$ in this case depends only on the initial and final state?

Comment: Forgive me, but I never intended to imply you were using the "authority principle". I have followed your contributions and respect your work

Comment: In any case, I think I found Zemansky's argument in the case of adiabatic work on pp 76 and 77 of 9th ed. I'm thinking this depends on the definition of a state function (thermodynamic property). If path independence is both a necessary and sufficient condition to call something a state function or property, then I suppose adiabatic work and isochoric heat would have to be considered state functions. But I’m not so sure about the sufficient part. I will need to give this more thought. Thanks

Comment: Would you be interested in continuing with this in Chat?

Comment: @BobD Unfortunately, I can't. I have a couple of long meetings starting right now. Probably tomorrow around this hour I could.

Comment: No rush and no need to commit to a time. I'm retired so I'm flexible. Just wanted to know if you were interested.  When and if you have the time, just enter the Chat room.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122970/discussion-between-bob-d-and-giorgiop).